# Firebase hosting - user custom domain (white-labeling)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase for one of my apps and looking to add functionality where my users can customize the domain name and to use their own instead.

So instead of my app's "example.com/bla" they can update it to "mydomain.com/bla" as a premium branding feature (white-labeling).

Is it possible with firebase hosting/functions and if so how to achieve that?

One of the examples of what I'm looking for can be found here:
https://www.surveyhero.com/white-label-surveys?ref=features-table

Comment: You can associate multiple domains with the same project/site. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites. Whether this is enough for your use-case is hard to tell for us, so you might want to give it a try and report back if you run into a problem.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. The idea is that the users of my application can assign their domain right from the app. One of the examples of such feature can be found here: https://www.surveyhero.com/white-label-surveys?ref=features-table. The idea is that every user can have their custom domain while as far as I can see from the doc one project is limited to 36 custom domains so I'd assume it's not possible to do this with firebase hosting?

Comment: Here is another link that describes how such feature can be set up if that helps: https://help.surveyhero.com/manual/how-to-use-your-own-domain-for-your-online-surveys-white-label/

Comment: I don't think there is an API to add custom domains to Firebase Hosting, so it'd definitely require manual work on your part for each. But in general Firebase projects are not meant to host multiple white labeled customers, as you're mixing their resources in that case. In general you should set up a separate project for each customer.

Comment: got you @FrankvanPuffelen. Reading through the docs again I can now see that the limit of "36" is actually for the number of websites associated with one project and not the number of custom domains. So I'm wondering if there is a limit for the number of custom domains in one project? While the manual set up is fine I'm thinking to associated each user's credentials with their domain so only authorized user can access the "backend" functionality of the app through that domain. That should help to keep their resources separate while managing my users through a single project if that makes sense

Comment: Firebase Hosting is not well-suited for multi-tenant domain provisioning. Going above 20 domains on a single site is not recommended and can cause provisioning delays and other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this question as answered, pasting here the comment by Michael Bleigh:

> Firebase Hosting is not well-suited for multi-tenant domain
> provisioning. Going above 20 domains on a single site is not
> recommended and can cause provisioning delays and other issues.

So the answer would be "no, it's not really possible (at least by the moment of writing this answer) since it won't scale past 20 domains."